# Сместился текст из-за картинки в сторону

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вернуть текст обратно? Что бы он был как у первого столбца.

```css
body {
    background: #39a0b9;
}

/*Block Twitter*/
.twiter{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}

span{
    color: #9ae2f4;
}

h2{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.from-twitert img{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 55px;
    top: -80px;
}

.from-twiterb img{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 55px;
    top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
   <div class="twiter clearfix">
    <footer>
    <h2>From Twitter</h2>
    <div class="from-twitert tw"><br>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply <br>
    dummy text of the printing<br>
    and <span>typesetting industry.</span><br> 
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span> has been the </p>
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/15b4575f637fce429a3a2823eb6761d2-full.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="from-twiterb tw"><br>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply <br>
    dummy text of the printing <br>
    and <span>typesetting industry.</span> <br>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span> has been the</p>
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/15b4575f637fce429a3a2823eb6761d2-full.png" alt="">
    </div>
    </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотя я вроде бы идентично указал параметры для обоих столбцов

Comment: Что-то не воспроизводится с этим кодом. Сделай чтоб воспроизводилось.

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде бы сделал

Comment: @BraFik Дополнил ответ

Comment: @Влад Благодарю сейчас гляну

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  background: #39a0b9;
}

.twiter {
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

span {
  color: #9ae2f4;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.from-twiter {
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin: 2em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.from-twiter img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.from-twiter p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer class="twiter">
  <h2>From Twitter</h2>
  <div class="from-twiter">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/15b4575f637fce429a3a2823eb6761d2-full.png">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and <span>typesetting industry.</span> <span>Lorem Ipsum</span> has been the </p>
  </div>

  <div class="from-twiter">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/15b4575f637fce429a3a2823eb6761d2-full.png">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and <span>typesetting industry.</span> <span>Lorem Ipsum</span> has been the</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле второй абзац сдвигает первая картинка. Вы можете убедиться в этом удалив временно вторую картинку.

Вашу задачу решает, например, абсолютное позиционирование картинок в родительском блоке. Например так:

```
    .from-twitert, .from-twiterb {
        position: relative;
    }
    .from-twitert img, .from-twiterb img{
        position: absolute;
        left: -70px;
        top: 30px;
    }
```

Но в любом случае, во времена flex размещать элементы относительным позиционированием как-то странно :-)

Я бы решал так:

Стили

```
<style>
    .twiter {
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .tw  {
        display: flex;
    }
    .tw img {
        width:  50px;
        height: 50px;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    .tw p {
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Верстка

```
<div class="twiter clearfix">
    <footer>
        <div class="tw">
            <img src="img/Twitter.png" alt="">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the </p>
        </div>

        <div class="tw">
            <img src="img/Twitter.png" alt="">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а каким образом ещё их размещать если относительным позиционированием странно?

Comment: @BraFik а для чего вообще вам нужно какое либо позиционирование, если вы можете поставить картинку перед текстом и обойтись без лишних телодвижений?

Comment: @Cheg Да я бы и не против без лишних тело движений, но просто пока мало знаю, и приходится мучатся из-за этого)